# Copy records from one table to another using spark-sql-jdbc

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do POC in pyspark on a very simple requirement. As a first step, I am just trying to copy the table records from one table to another table. There are more than 20 tables but at first, I am trying to do it only for the one table and later enhance it to multiple tables.

The below code is working fine when I am trying to copy only 10 records. But, when I am trying to copy all records from the main table, this code is getting stuck and eventually I have to terminate it manually. As the main table has 1 million records, I was expecting it to happen in few seconds, but it just not getting completed.

**Spark UI :**

[image]

Could you please suggest how should I handle it ?

```
Host : Local Machine
Spark verison : 3.0.0
database : Oracle
```

**Code :**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from configparser import ConfigParser

#read configuration file
config  = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

#setting up db credentials
url     = config['credentials']['dbUrl']
dbUsr   = config['credentials']['dbUsr']
dbPwd   = config['credentials']['dbPwd']
dbDrvr  = config['credentials']['dbDrvr']
dbtable = config['tables']['dbtable']

#print(dbtable)

# database connection 
def dbConnection(spark):

    pushdown_query = "(SELECT * FROM main_table) main_tbl"
    prprDF = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
        .option("url",url)\
        .option("user",dbUsr)\
        .option("dbtable",pushdown_query)\
        .option("password",dbPwd)\
        .option("driver",dbDrvr)\
        .option("numPartitions", 2)\
        .load()



    prprDF.write.format("jdbc")\
        .option("url",url)\
        .option("user",dbUsr)\
        .option("dbtable","backup_tbl")\
        .option("password",dbPwd)\
        .option("driver",dbDrvr)\
        .mode("overwrite").save()


if __name__ =="__main__":
    
    spark = SparkSession\
            .builder\
            .appName("DB refresh")\
            .getOrCreate()

    dbConnection(spark)
    spark.stop()
```

Comment: why are you using the spark to just copy the table? It depends on the network than.

Comment: We have a refresh process which takes around 5 hours. We were thinking if this could be done in Spark? there are some more transformations involved but copying records from one table to another is the first step.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using only one thread(executor) to process the data by using JDBC connection. Can you check the executors and driver details in Spark UI and try increasing the resources. Also share the error by which it's failing. You can get this from the same UI or use CLI to logs "yarn logs -applicationId "